# Convert VBscript to VB.Net or C#.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, vbscript

**Is there any tool to convert VBscript code to VB.net Code or C#.net?**

this is the sample code I want to convert it

```
Dim googleTime, googleDt, googleScheme
googleTime = DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", Now())
googleDt = (1000 * googleTime) + Round(1000 * (Timer - Int(Timer)))
googleScheme = "http://"
googleUserAgent = Server.URLEncode(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))
If StrComp(Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS"), "on") = 0 Then googleScheme = "https://"
```

for example *Timer* in VBscript I did not find any equivalent in VB.Net
Please advice.

Comment: For that amount of code it would probably be quicker just to google the equivalent code in the other language

Comment: I am not such a VB.Net expert, but there seems to be some timer: http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer-vbnet

Comment: I guess, there's no automated tool for VBScript to C# due to some potential problems. You might want to check this out: http://www.netcoole.com/asp2aspx/vbhtml/csharp.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The Timer function returns the number of seconds, and milliseconds, since 12:00 AM."

http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_timer.asp

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Today).TotalMilliseconds
```

is the equivalent.